# How to filter rows in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to filter rows in a dataframe using a set of conditions.

First, create an example dataframe.

```
example = pd.DataFrame({
'Name': ['Joe', 'Alice', 'Steve', 'Jennie','Katie','Vicky','Natalia','Damodardas'],
'Age': [33, 39, 22, 42, 23, 24, 22, 56]})
```

Now, I need to know the people in the age group of 30-40 years. One way is to **sequentially** apply the conditions on age (see below).

```
example = example.loc[example.Age>=30]
example = example.loc[example.Age<40]
print(example)
```

Is there another option to **simultaneously** apply both conditions? The code below throws an error.

```
example = example.loc[example.Age>=30 and example.Age<40]
print(example)
```

Comment: You need to use bitwise operators to chain multiple comparisons. There's plenty of info out there on this, for instance [Bitwise operators and chaining comparisons in Pandas](https://towardsdatascience.com/bitwise-operators-and-chaining-comparisons-in-pandas-d3a559487525)

Answer (score 3):

in pandas you cannot use the `and` or `or` operations:

instead use the `&`:

```
example = example.loc[(example.Age>=30 ) & (example.Age<40) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is right, just use "&" instead of "and"

```
example = example.loc[(example.Age>=30)&(example.Age<40)]
print(example)
```

or you can also do it without loc:

```
example = example[(example['Age']>=30)&(example['Age']<40)]
print(example)
```

Answer (score 1):

One of possible options is to use *between* function.

```
example = example.loc[example.Age.between(30, 39)]
```

Note: This function has *inclusive* parameter (default *True*).

Other possibility is to use *query* function, in your case:

```
example = example.query('Age >= 30 and Age < 40')
```

*query* is quite a powerful function. Read the documentation to learn more.